# Adding downloaded MODIS data to array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am downloading MODIS LST data in Matlab. The outputted data I have appears like this:

[image: matlab command window]

I have no problems with downloading the data, just how can I save this data into a new array. I want this data to just go into the first column, next set into the second etc...

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to convert your matrix from class Uint16/unit8 to double.

```
lst =double(your_matrix_name);
```

then, you can arrange the data into an array of desired columns and rows.

```
lst1=reshape(lst, [rows columns]);

eg: lst1=reshape(lst, [365 1]); for 365 rows and 1 column
```